# Does neo4j have all the proper apis and support for all the mentioned drivers?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient, node-neo4j

I used Node js for my webapp and  I wanted to create a new user with unique email ID and hence that required me to look up the index table but then I realised that the Node Driver doesn't have the index() function as the one in Java( graphDb.index() ). Any work around for such an issue, like using REST or some Cypher connetor

Answer (score 3):

Neo4j just so happens to have a wonderful REST API that should work for your application. The docs for the api are detailed here:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html.

It even has an entire section devoted to indexing.

Comment: Was this helpful? Would you like a more concrete example? Maybe example code?